# Reading a parameter from a PHP file inside HTML

Tags: php, if-statement

I have very basic knowledge of PHP and programming in general. I'm trying to find a way to display some text on a website only if a certain parameter exists in a PHP file inside a directory on the server. Check out the example below to see what I want to do:

```
<div>
    if ( 'read "$parameter" from file website-root/addons/example.php') {
        echo 'Text 1';
    } else {
        echo 'Text 2';
    };
</div>
```

What do I put instead of `read "$parameter" from file website-root/addons/example.php`? Please note that the file that contains the above code is placed in a different directory on the root of the website, if that matters.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to include `example.php` in this file by using one of the following - [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), [`include_once`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php), [`require`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php), [`require_once`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) - and then check if it exists - [`if(isset($parameter))`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Comment: You can only use defined variables from the example.php. the dynamilcally changed variables aren't available.

Comment: @MarcusRommel Yes, the variables are defined. There are 5 different variables set in the example.php file. Only one needs to get a different text output on the website.

Comment: Can you show us the php file content? I think you could use a include or a regex match.

Answer (score 0):

To include the static variables from your example.php use the include statement.

http://php.net/manual/de/function.include.php

But I would suggest to write all these variables in an extra php and include this php in all the files where you need them.
Like this: include 'vars.php';

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to the "include" way right now. I only need it in one html file.

Comment: I only have html files, it's a template inside a script written in PHP. I tried to add <?php include('addons/example.php') ?> and use the if statement exemplified by user Sean above, but it doesn't work. I'm missing something.

Comment: In order to execute php code your file needs to be a php file. A html file can't contain php code.

Comment: You're right, thank again! The way I see it, I'll have to create a PHP file with the above code and add a <TAG> instead of Text 1 and Text 2, which will be defined in the PHP file, right?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean. Please give a example

Comment: Neither do I :-) So, where I said “Text 1” and “Text 2” in the example, it is actually a combination between Plain Text and <TAGS>, which are defined in the example.php file from the addons directory. Please note that the addons/example.php file’s main purpose is to enable a single <TAG> used in the HTML file inside the template dir, along with other <TAGS> defined in other PHP files outside the template folder. OK?

Comment: Here’s how the DIV inside the HTML file looks now: “You have <TAG1> cars from <TAG2> available (<TAG3> cars remain)”. (those <TAGS> represents numbers defined in variables inside certain PHP files.

Everything was ok until recently, when new car model was added in the static variables inside the addons/example.php file. Therefore, I want to get rid of the <TAG3> from the above example: (<TAG3> cars remain) … and display only “You have <TAG1> cars from <TAG2> available” for the new model. (It’s not about cars, just an example).

Comment: Try it. If you have more problems, ask us. If you don't know much about php/programming try codecademy.com. its free and very good.